# Need to show sum of column value at end rdlc file?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, reportingservices-2005, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm working on `rdlc file` getting values from stored procedure from that i have created dataset to show all values on `rdlc file`.

> Need to show AVG of column value at end `rdlc file` how to do this?

I tried with `AVG aggregate function using expression` but problem is how to group by my column ?

guide me. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `=sum(Fields!Time.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!groupingField.Value)`, where `Fields!Time.Value` is your field with time values and `Fields!groupingField.Value` is your field that you use for row grouping.

Comment: Thanks i'm new to rdlc please tell me how can I use row grouping in my case?

Comment: 1. Add new table to your report. 2. Go to tablix properties 3. Select your dataset name and click ok 4. Click on your table, so that you'll see in Row Groups area, group named "Details" 5. Right click on this group and go to group properties. 6. Click Add button to add field by which you want to group values.

Comment: getting error 
The definition of the report '' is invalid.
 More than one dataset, data region, or grouping in the report has the name ‘Group1’. Dataset, data region, and grouping names must be unique within a report.

Comment: All groups, datasets etc must be unique within the report. You need to change the name for the "Group1".

Comment: yea but i'm not getting name in properties :( also please tell me

Comment: i'm getting this error after adding new table in rdlc :( and i do not find Group1 name anywhere :(

Comment: Try to create new rdl file.

Comment: I did :( same error could you please share any link which is similar to my question

Comment: Try to restart visual studio. Sometimes it caches reports and displays incorrect results.